# onclick event trigger several times Onsen UI Angular + JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

what is wrong with this code?

```
 $(document).on("click",".item-from-list",function(){
```

It works fine. But after I use navigator.replacePage(); It triggers the same time that I used replacePage();
Eg:
I have a button that user select a day and it returns data.
When user change the day, It uses navigator.replacePage(); and then is the problem. Now, if user click on list item, it triggers the event the same times the user has changed the day.

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="ListController">
      <ons-gesture-detector id="gd">
        <ons-carousel>
          <ons-carousel-item>
            <div class="item-label">
               <ons-scroller>
                  <ul class="list-i">
                      <li ng-repeat="data in itens" class="item-from-list">
```

I tried to use $(element).click(function); but it did not worked.
Can someone help me?

Comment: `$(document).on("click",".item-from-list",function(e){
e.stopPropagation();` try doing it with this

Comment: How about simply using ng-click on your <li>'s ? Also, calling event.stopPropagation() or event.preventDefault() may help.

Comment: I tried it all too but no sucess. I cannot use ngclick or onclick. Must be jquery. I'm sad.